# newsletter new subscriber

Tags: magento2

I want to use a newsletter subcriber that a customer can add his e-mail to the newsletter_subscriber table.

I use the following code:

```
<form class="form subscribe" method="post" action="/newsletter/subscriber/new/" >
<div class="form_search">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-form">
<div class="text_form">VERPASSEN SIE KEINE AKTION!</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-field">
<div class="form-newletter"><input class="search_input" name="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" /> <button class="subscribe" type="submit">Newsletter<br />Anmelden</button></div>
<div class="dsgvo"><input required="" type="checkbox" /> Ich akzeptiere die <a href="/datenschutz" target="_blank">Datenschutzbedingungen</a> von AGO-Shop.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

But when I insert my e-mail and click the button no e-mail address will be added.

Also the standard magento code:

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

is not working.

Hope someone can help me.
kindly regards

Comment: I checked with the above same Block class defined "{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}" and it worked for me fine. Are you sure you don't have any customization of subscribe.phtml or something that might be causing the issue otherwise native code is working fine with above block defined.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I don't know about changes of the file subscribe.phtml.
Here is my file subscribe.phtml: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdfbl03c0chkuh5/subscribe.phtml?dl=0
Hope someone can still help me there and maybe someone can find the problem.
kindly regards

Comment: I want ask if someone can still help me here. kindly regards